# Can django consume rest api to make a beautiful CRUD web app?

Tags: django, rest

My partner control mysql database and supply me a rest web service , I will call this rest api to finish CRUD (create , retrieve , update , delete)  operation .

I perform to use django framework , after spend some time to study , I find django can easily finish CRUD by using the database it migrated . but in my case , I will call rest api to operate remote mysql database .

Is django the suitable framework to finish this work ? or if any other framework can finish it with beautiful UI , please give me some suggest

Answer (score 0):

Django is a server side component. Your partners REST web service is also a server side component. From the tiny bit we know, it is possible that Django is just not necessary here.

So if his API is complete enough, maybe you could build a frontend in Javascript that talks to his web service directly and forget about Django.

Or maybe not (how do you do deal with passwords for the database, user login etc?!), but we can't tell from a little bit of information and it wouldn't really fit in a Stack Overflow answer anyway.

Comment: sorry, I also feel this question not fit here , because I know so littel about frontend , if let me use javascript to make CRUD web app to call rest api , I am afraid can not finish , so trying to find a example or framework

Comment: How will you make a "beautiful web app" without knowing much about the frontend? Anyway, I can't really answer more than the above.